# How to pass a component to all components inside <router-views/>?

Tags: vue.js

This is my App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <router-view /> // contains the differents pages of the app
    <app-sign-up-modal></app-sign-up-modal>
    <app-player></app-player>
  </div>
</template>
```

Inside the router-view I have a `Home.vue` component which itself has a `Header.vue` component which has a full height and width background image. My problem is that because my `<app-navbar></app-navbar>` component has padding, the background image of `Header.vue` has some ugly black padding because in the DOM the navbar is outside the header, like that:

```
<div id="app">
  <nav class="navbar></navbar>
  <div class="home">
    <header class="home__header"></header>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to pass `<app-navbar></app-navbar>` to `Header.vue` while still being a global component, how can I do that?

Comment: If you would to that, wouldn't you be displaying <app-navbar> twice? (Once in App.vue and once in Home.vue)

Comment: @JoshuaAngnoe The ideal would be to place <app-navbar> inside the view-router tag like a slot so it applies to every component affected by view-router but it doesn't seem to work, I get an error

Comment: There are several ways to do it. One would be to use slots. Another would be to use vue-portal (plugin in vue 2; part of core in vue 3). Yet another way would be to give `<router-view>` a negative top margin and a top padding to make it render its background under the header. Another one would to use `position: absolute` on the header + an appropriate top padding on the `<router-view>`. And, finally, you could use `display:grid` to position a background-element under both header and `<router-view>`. It looks like you've done no research whatsoever.

Comment: @tao I already tried using `<teleport>`, it gives me an error saying the target is out of reach. I also tried with `slot` which would be I think the most appropriate approch but when I pass any data inside `<router-view></router-view>`, even a simple string, all the pages tied to this component go blank Idk why